# How to re-use a bunch of code when 2 objects are involved in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have faced this issue many times, but finally asking how to solve this in Swift and iOS. I have the same code block that runs against 2 different kind of objects, but I can't figure out, how to apply the code to either of the 2 object types with it being strongly typed. In other languages (like PHP) I would just put a generic `var myVar = nil` at the top of block and then set that to one or the other of those objects, then hang the code off of it, but swift won't let me do that.

How do you handle this programming situation in Swift/iOS?

```
static func entitySetup(jsonObject: JSON, object: MyCoreDataEntityObject?) {
    if let existingObj = object { // existingObj = a MyCoreDataEntityObject
        existingObj.setValue(jsonObject["firstName"].stringValue, forKey: "firstName")
        existingObj.setValue(jsonObject["lastName"].stringValue, forKey: "lastName")
        existingObj.setValue(jsonObject["address"].stringValue, forKey: "address")
        existingObj.setValue(jsonObject["phone"].stringValue, forKey: "phone")
    } else { // newObj = NSManagedObject
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyCoreDataEntityObject", in: self.context)
        let newObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
        newObj.setValue(jsonObject["firstName"].stringValue, forKey: "firstName")
        newObj.setValue(jsonObject["lastName"].stringValue, forKey: "lastName")
        newObj.setValue(jsonObject["address"].stringValue, forKey: "address")
        newObj.setValue(jsonObject["phone"].stringValue, forKey: "phone")
    }
    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("ERROR: Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both objects are `NSManagedObject`, you can do this:

```
let mangedObject: NSManagedObject
if let existingObj = object {
    managedObject = existingObj
} else {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyCoreDataEntityObject", in: self.context)
    managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.context)
}

managedObject.setValue(jsonObject["firstName"].stringValue, forKey: "firstName")
managedObject.setValue(jsonObject["lastName"].stringValue, forKey: "lastName")
managedObject.setValue(jsonObject["address"].stringValue, forKey: "address")
managedObject.setValue(jsonObject["phone"].stringValue, forKey: "phone")

do {
    try self.context.save()
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("ERROR: Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    completionHandler(false)
}
```

And as suggested, the four lines calling `setValue` can be simplified as:

```
for key in ["firstName", "lastName", "address", "phone"] {
    managedObject.setValue(jsonObject[key].stringValue, forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: You can also iterate over `["firstName", "lastName", "address", "phone"]`.

Comment: @Sulthan can you give an example of iterating over these values (first, last, etc)? Keeping in mind that they are not always strings.

Comment: @Dan I added the additional simplification I believe Sulthan was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static func entitySetup(jsonObject: JSON, object: MyCoreDataEntityObject?) {

    let newObject = object ?? NSManagedObject(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyCoreDataEntityObject", in: self.context)!, insertInto: self.context)

    for key in ["firstName", "lastName", "address", "phone"] {
        newObject.setValue(jsonObject[key].stringValue, forKey: key)
    }

    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("ERROR: Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```